# Custom block panelizer settings

Tags: 7, blocks, panels

**Can anyone advice me on how I can include a settings/configuration form for my custom module within Panelizer?**

[image]

I'm working on a custom module which uses an API to display data to a user.
The block contains a form which is placed on a page via Panelizer.

My block displays with no problems but I need to allow some settings to be made on each occurrence of the block on the same or different pages.